# Cross-plone-site URLs give weird combination

Tags: plone

I have two plone sites being served up by the same plone setup, each accessed by two different domain names, which point to the same IP address. An apache front end has virtual hosts and mod_proxy set up to target the URLs to the appropiate plone sites. In summary:

```
DNS:
  mysite1.com -> my machine's IP address
  mysite2.com ->      ditto

Plone:
    2 Plone sites: site1, site2

Apache:
    2 virtual hosts defined:
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/mysite1.com:80/site1/VirtualHostRoot/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/mysite1.com:80/site1/VirtualHostRoot/

    and

      ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/mysite2.com:80/site2/VirtualHostRoot/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/mysite2.com:80/site2/VirtualHostRoot/
```

This allows the URL mysite1.com to go to plone "site1" and mysite2.com to go to plone "site2".

All this works.

However if in a browser I visit: mysite1.com/site2 then I get the contents of site2 with some elements of the theme from each site. Likewise if I visit mysite2.com/site1 then I get a mix up of content and themes from the two sites.

I know that these URLs are not visible anywhere - it's just me typing them in - I just worry that this cross-talk does happen, and therefore what implication are there for different security domains that I have in each site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is called [Acquisition](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/Acquisition.html); attributes inherited from an object's containment rather than from it's class hierarchy.

You do not need to worry that this removes the security containment from your sites. Users defined in either site1 or site2 do not gain additional permissions to access the acquired site, and only anonymous (public) information and methods can be accessed this way.

If you access either site with a user defined at the top level (so the root Zope object containing the two sites), then you *can* access protected information on either site, acquired or not.

The only risk at cross-talk, is if your sites rely on being able to access a skin method or object with the same id as the other site object, and that skin method or object is gone (deleted, for example). Your code could then end up accessing the acquired site object instead, with unpredictable results as the acquired site is obviously not the same thing as your code would expect. For skin methods and such, security would not permit you from doing any harm. Browser views and other python-level code, could of course end up doing harm, but this should be quite a rare combination of circumstances. If your sites do not have ids likely to clash with your site contents there is no need to be concerned about this.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, for the explanation. I think it's something that I wont loose too much sleep over. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's the bless/curse of [Acquisition](http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/Acquisition). [Here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.zope.plone.user/37056) 's a solution.

Comment: Note that this is not going to be easy; you'll have to define a *new* top-level object that alters the acquisition behavior, not something for the faint of heart in any case.

Comment: Someone could argue that if you don't try you can't fail :). Anyway I've already faced that strange behaviour before and imho it's something that we should fix, one way or another. As you say, it's not really dangerous, but when a newcomer discovers this the first thing that he think is that he found a huge and dangerous bug (as I did at the time)

Comment: It is something the Zope community *is* fixing, but it is such a fundamental technology to what Zope is *now* that it'll take a while to do so. :-)

Comment: Thanks, guys, for the insights. I don't think I will be dashing off and implementing a new top-level site object - too many things that I could break, particularly if this is something that will get improved by Zope at some point.